# How to decode celery message in SQS

Tags: django, encoding, celery, amazon-sqs, decoding

Some of celery tasks in sqs are pending forever, I want to read those messages (tasks) before deleting.
On going to sqs console, I am able to see the encoded message I tried decoding it with

```
value = base64.b64decode(value.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
```

This gives me dict dump with keys

```
['body', 'headers', 'content-type', 'properties', 'content-encoding']
```

In this dict body lookes like encoded 
I tried to decode it with same

```
value = base64.b64decode(value.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
```

but it gives error saying 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 1: invalid start byte

Am I missing something?
How to decode this messages? Is there is any way to decode it?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that "Celery" uses "pickle.dump" to turn the payload of the task into bytes, and then encode to base64. Doing the reverse operation we get the payload again.

```
import base64
import boto3
import pickle

queue_name = 'your-queue-name'
sqsr = boto3.resource('sqs')
queue = sqsr.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=queue_name)

for message in queue.receive_messages(MaxNumberOfMessages=10):
    print(f'{message.message_id} >>> {message.receipt_handle}'
          f' >>> {message.body} >>> {message.message_attributes}')
    body_dict = json.loads(base64.b64decode(message.body))
    celery_payload = pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(body_dict.get('body')))
    print(celery_payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the following points to make it work upon getting the following error:

If it gives the error for  "_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '['"

1. Add  Missing Library "import json" above
2. Provide Credentials to the boto3.resource function call
3. There is no need to unpickle the paylaod as it seems Celery doesnt use pickle.dump rather base64.encode Only

   ```
   import boto3
   import pickle
   import json

   queue_name = 'your-queue-name'
   sqs = boto3.resource('sqs', region_name="your_region_name",
           aws_access_key_id="your_access_key",
           aws_secret_access_key="your_secret_key")
   queue = sqsr.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=queue_name)

   for message in queue.receive_messages(MaxNumberOfMessages=10):
       print(f'{message.message_id} >>> {message.receipt_handle}'
             f' >>> {message.body} >>> {message.message_attributes}')
       body_dict = json.loads(base64.b64decode(message.body))
       celery_payload = base64.b64decode(body_dict.get('body'))
       print(celery_payload)
   ```